# Percentile 75 in access Database

Tags: database, ms-access, percentile

I'm trying to get the percentile 75 in an access database and I can't get it done. I need the 75 percentile of the prices for each city. The 75 percentile ordered upward. Thank you!!

This is the example database:

```
Return Ciudad Kayak     Price    
Lima                     360$   
Lima                     420$     
CMX                      300$    
CMX                      400$    
Cancun                   350$     
Cancun                   500$     
Cusco                    50$      
Cusco                    60$      
Cancun                   300$     
Cusco                    70$      
Cusco                    30$
```

Result:

```
Return Ciudad Kayak     Percentile 75    
Lima                     xxx$      
CMX                      xxx$       
Cancun                   xxx$       
Cusco                    xxx$
```

Comment: What numbers do you expect in the output?

Comment: In the output I want the percentile 75 of the prices of each city. That query would work for a specific city (city = "Cusco") but I want the output to show all the cities.

This query five me the percentile 75 for all prices, but not grouped by city.

`SELECT Min(T1.Price) AS Percentile75
FROM [Kayak desde Lima] AS T1
WHERE ((((SELECT COUNT (*)
               FROM [Kayak desde Lima] As T2
               WHERE T2.Price <= T1.Price))>=((SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM [Kayak desde Lima])*0.75)))
ORDER BY Min(T1.Price);`

Comment: Edit your question to show actual expected output based on the sample data as well as attempted query.